# Why do these functions don't work

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I don't understand why only the `stFunction()` works? Why I got the syntax error (unexpected token ".") at the `ndFunction()` and what's wrong with `rdFunction()`? Thank you for help

```
function stFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("id1");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
function ndFunction() {
    var y.value = document.getElementById("id2").value.toUpperCase();
}
function rdFunction() {
    var y = {};
    y.value = document.getElementById("id3").value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: this isn't valid javascript: `var y.value = `

Comment: `and what's wrong with rdFunction()` - if there's nothing in the console about rdFunction, then there's nothing wrong with it ... executing the function will appear to do exactly nothing, because it effectively does nothing, it reads a value, and stores it in a var that is thrown away when the function finishes, and the function returns nothing - so, unless you're getting a console error, it does exactly what you've written

Comment: @Jaromanda X - I'm sorry but I really don't see difference between stFunction and rdFunction. Is there reason why they acts differently? Just stFunction works when I use them like this: Enter your name: <input type="text" id="id1" onchange="stFunction()">
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="id3" onchange="rdFunction()">

Comment: @M_V y is a simple object  ... x is a particular HTML element ... assigning to y.value does nothing visual, assigning to x.value changes the web page

Comment: I probably confused this site for forum where you ask questions when you don't understand something. Now I get it. This place is just for "clever" questions right... Really sorry if my dull question offends somebody.

Answer (score 5):

Your ndFunction isn't working because y doesn't exist when you try to set it's property. As for rdFunction as long as your element exists and has a value it should work just fine.

```
function ndFunction() {
    var y = {},
        y.value = document.getElementById("id2").value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why I got the syntax error (unexpected token ".") at the `ndFunction()`

When you write `var y.value = document.getElementById("id2").value.toUpperCase();`,
you are actually defining a variable named `y.value` which is not a valid variable name (https://mothereff.in/js-variables#y.value). The dot is a property accessors, that is why you're getting the syntax error *unexpected token "."*. It is trying to access the property named `value` for the variable `y` that you didn't define before.

> and what's wrong with rdFunction()?

Nothing is wrong with `rdFunction()`. You are creating an object named `y` using an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Then you are defining the property named `value` for this object and the value of the property `value` will be `document.getElementById("id3").value.toUpperCase();`. Try a `console.log(y)` at the end of `rdFunction()`. You'll see that everything works fine. Note that you also could have defined the property `value` like this

```
var y = {};
y['value'] = document.getElementById("id3").value.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dontfeedthecode has the point.
If `stFunction` works, you can do the same as `stFunction` for `ndFunction` :D
on ndFunction:

```
function ndFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("id2");
    y.value = y.value.toUpperCase();
}
```